# Sharepoint 2013 - How to add a footer to the oslo Masterpage

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to add a footer to my public facing website. It uses the Oslo masterpage. I'd like to know which file I need to edit and where. I have SP 2013 Designer installed. Could anyone help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

### Master Page Gallery

The top-level SharePoint Server site for a site collection hosted on SharePoint Server has a special document library called the Master Page and Page Layout Gallery. All page layouts and master pages are stored in this document library.

### To navigate a master page gallery in SharePoint Designer

in the Navigation pane, choose the Master Pages site object.

Refer an article [Overview of the SharePoint 2013 page model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj191506.aspx#bk_MasterPages) to understand the parts of a SharePoint site and how a SharePoint page is put together

---

> In SharePoint 2013, if the master page, for example, `oslo.master` is
>   associated with a html page, i.e., `oslo.html`, you cannot edit the
>   .master page directly. You should edit the html page with your
>   favorite html editor(for example, Visual Studio), find the right place
>   to insert your  tag. SharePoint will automatically synchronize
>   your change to the .html file to the .master.

For more information follow [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/31c8c028-52ed-43ed-8539-1cb25d892628/basic-footer-for-sharepoint-2013-masterpage?forum=sharepointcustomization)

From another hand, in order to edit master page directly, the association with html page should be broken.

Below is demonstrated how to break the master page association and customize the footer in master page file.

### Example

1) Open `Olso.master` in Edit mode

2) Select `Save as` action to save it as a custom master page, let's name it, lets say, `helsinki.master` (`helsinki.master` is **not** associated with html page, it means it could be edited directly )

3) Open `helsinki.master` and find `DeltaPlaceHolderFooter`

4) To specify custom footer, replace the block

```
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderFooter" BlockElement="true" runat="server">
   <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="PageFooter" AllowMultipleControls="false" />
</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
```

with

```
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderFooter" BlockElement="true" runat="server">
  <%--SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="PageFooter" AllowMultipleControls="false" /--%>
   <div id="footer" class="noindex">
       <p style="text-align:center;">Some fancy footer is displayed here.</p>
   </div>
</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
```

Result

[image]

Comment: I knew all of that already, but it doesn't say anything about the footer.

Comment: The answer has been updated

Comment: Thank you very much, Vadim. That worked. I am now try to add another text on the right of the centre text, but non the same line. I tried span and float but it keeps adding it on another line which makes the footer area bigger. Could you help me with that? Thanks.